# what do we mean by Feasible and reporting distance?

Tags: networking, cisco, eigrp

what do we mean by Feasible  and reporting distance  ?   i read many referance but i don't understand it if anyone have an example or picture to explain it in EIGRP

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In EIGRP, the "feasible distance" (FD) is the lowest metric known for a specific route.

By extrapolation, I suspect that the "reporting distance" is whatever metric a neighbor sends, we then add the metric of the link that update came across (or, possibly, the link that is the best link to the next hop; these should ideally be the same, but...).

Once you have a FD, any update whose total metric is the same as the FD for that route will simply add "feasible successors" top the route. Any route with a better metric will update the FD and provide a single successor.